# ConcurrentModificationException while streaming HashSet during anyMatch call

Tags: java, multithreading

```
    private Set<Job> myJobs = new HashSet<>();

    public shouldDoWork(Work work)
        return !myJobs.stream()
                  .map(job -> job.doWork(work))
                  .anyMatch(shouldDoWork -> !shouldDoWork);


   public addJob(Job job) {
       myJobs.add(job);
   }
   // also for remove
```

and there are many threads calling any of this function at any time

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.tryAdvance(HashMap.java:1579) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:449) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at

any idea why ConcurrentModificationException is thrown?

is it because the set (`myJobs`) is changing or if because the value of `shouldDoWork` is being changed by something else?

Comment: Does `Job#doWork` happen to add/remove element(s) from `myJobs`?

Comment: job.doWork(work) - looks like doWork is modifying job.

Comment: @JacobG. no it does not but there are other threads do add/remove myJobs

Comment: also the exception is thrown during anyMatch, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> any idea why ConcurrentModificationException is thrown?

Yes.

> is it because the set (myJobs) is changing or if because the value of
>   shouldDoWork is being changed by something else?

The former.  You list two methods, `shouldDoWork()` and `addJob()`.  The first performs a stream operation on the set `myJobs`, and the second adds an element to that set.  If indeed

> there are many threads calling any of this function at any time

then it is likely that at some point a thread will invoke `addJob()`, thereby *structurally modifying* set `myJobs`, between the time that another constructs a stream from that set and when that other finishes consuming that stream.  Modifying the objects in the set will not cause a `ConcurrentModificationException` (though it could more generally invalidate the set if doing so changes elements' hash codes).  It is modifying the set itself that can do.

You're lucky, in fact, that you get a CME, because that's not guaranteed in the case of improperly synchronized modification such as you depict.  You might instead get a garbage result.

You have at least two plausible alternatives for *both* achieving proper synchronization and avoiding the CME:

1. **Synchronize accesses to `myJobs`**.  For example,

   ```
   public boolean shouldDoWork(Work work) {
       synchronized(myJobs) {
           return !myJobs.stream()
                 .map(job -> job.doWork(work))
                 .anyMatch(shouldDoWork -> !shouldDoWork);
       }
   }

   public addJob(Job job) {
       synchronized (myJobs) {
           myJobs.add(job);
       }
   }
   ```

   If you take this approach then you must similarly synchronize *all* accesses to `myJobs`. OR
2. **Use a different kind of container**, such as a `ConcurrentHashMap`, that does not require explicit synchronization

   ```
   private ConcurrentHashMap<Job, Job> myJobs = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

   public boolean shouldDoWork(Work work) {
       return !myJobs.keySet().stream()
             .map(job -> job.doWork(work))
             .anyMatch(shouldDoWork -> !shouldDoWork);
   }

   public addJob(Job job) {
       myJobs.put(job, job);
   }
   ```

   You should read the docs of your proposed alternative class (`ConcurrentHashMap` in this case) before implementing such a change, to be sure you understand the implications.  This alternative probably performs better than synchronization, but that comes at the expense of weaker behavioral guarantees.

Comment: it's a set so should i be using Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>())?

Comment: No, @ealeon, you should not.  `synchronizedSet()` produces a set whose *individual* operations are synchronized with each other, but that will not prevent a CME in your case because consuming the stream spans *multiple* individual operations.  Either of the specific solutions I offered will work for you.  Note in particular that although the second uses a map instead of a set, you can think of it as using the map's key set.  That's analogous to how `HashSet` is implemented internally, if that makes you feel better about it.

Comment: so i should be just using the "synchronized" block option?

Comment: Again, @ealeon, *either* of the two alternatives I offered can work for you.  They will require different kinds of modifications to the rest of the class.

Comment: thank you great. is one preferred over another? using synchronzied looks like the easiest solution but switching over to ConcurrentHashMap would better serve as long term solution because i can forget about when to needing to add synchronized

Comment: Neither is objectively better than the other in all areas.  The explicit synchronization option may be a bit clearer, but the `ConcurrentHashMap` option probably performs better, especially under high-concurrency conditions.  There may be additional, project-specific reasons to prefer one over the other.